# How can be CSS used to style web pages meant to be served by Lift when Lift uses CSS classes for the purpose of its own?

Tags: css, scala, lift

Lift framework seems to use `class="lift:something"` in HTML tags but what if I want to apply some ordinary CSS to this tag and want it to have an ordinary class name?

Answer (score 6):

Each HTML element can have multiple classes separated by spaces, e.g.

```
<div class="lift:something something-else"></div>
```

You can target one or more of those classes in your stylesheet.

If Lift doesn't let you apply your own classes to elements (I'm not a Scala programmer), you may need to apply classes to other elements instead, like wrapper `div`s, and select based on those:

```
<div class="something">
    <div class="lift:something"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use many classes in dom elements:

```
<div class="lift:something my_extra_css_class">
```

Or, if the styling is meant to be unique, you can use an id and style the id and not the class:

```
html:
<div class="lift:something" id='my_id'>

css:
#my_id{
  bla: blabla;
  foo: bar;
  fruit: banana;
  codfish: sausage;
  car: garage;
  cash: atm;
}
```